# How to custom the focus ring color of NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nstextfield, nssearchfield

I have a custom NSTextField, named `MySearchField`. When I put it on the top of NSVisualEffectView and run my app on macOS 11.x, ring focus color of the text field and background color of selected text both turns white.

[image]

It seems that there is no API to adjust this in Apple API Reference. But I found the style of search field on Mac App Store is what I want.

[image]

So, How should I solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Accent color seems to cause this problem. In this case, multicolor is selected. How to specify an accent color for NSTextField?

Comment: What settings did you use in `NSVisualEffectView`?  Have you tried NOT using `NSVisualEffectView`?  I see that the docs say "Don't change the vibrancy settings of standard AppKit views and controls."

Comment: @JWWalker In fact, `NSVisualEffectView ` I metioned above is a split item using sidebar behavior and no addtional settings are applied. Any controls added to top of the sidebar always has white focus ring, even changing the behavior to default the problem still occurs.

Comment: What's the behavior if you do the same for `textField.cell.controlView`?